# How do I use a buildtool with clang?

Tags: c, llvm, clang

I'm starting out with Linux programming, and I don't want to learn the gcc.
What buildtools can I use to compile large nested source directories with ease with clang? And cross platform? Cmake looks nice, but there is no mention of how to specify a different compiler.

edit: I'd like to use it with vim.

Comment: Those tools are mostly compiler-agnostic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To use clang with cmake, you simply set the CC variable:

CC=clang cmake ...

There's also CXX for the C++ compiler, ie CXX=clang++.

CC/CXX are standard variables and should work with any build system.